# Glideslope Width measuring

Tags: navigation, ils, glideslope

I want to make an inspection of GP system before flight check. The idea is to measure the width of the sector (roughly) by going 200 meters from the GP  and using a lifting platform to measure the DDM  whit the PNR.

By my calculations, 200 meters away from the antenna, the glideslope should be at 10,48 meters and  0.175DDM shold be 2.45 meters below and above the glideslope.

What are your opinions?

Comment: Hi there, it isn't clear what your actual question is?  Here on StackExchange, we try to have questions that can be answered with actual facts rather than opinions (which are more suited to **discussion forums** rather than a **question & answer** forum like here).  Please *Edit* your question and clarify what your question is if you would like our assistance.  Thank you!

Comment: This is elementary trigonometry.  tan(10.48/200) = 3 degrees.  Not much room for opinions.

Comment: DDM tolerances by category are found in Chicago convention, [annex 10](https://www.bazl.admin.ch/dam/bazl/en/dokumente/Fachleute/Regulationen_und_Grundlagen/icao-annex/icao_annex_10_aeronauticaltelecommunicationsvolumei-radionavigat.pdf.download.pdf/icao_annex_10_aeronauticaltelecommunicationsvolumei-radionavigat.pdf), attachment C, e.g. figures C-9/10/11.